# Neptune connectivity failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to hit my Neptune cluster in a production account. This works in my non-production account.

```
awscurl -X POST -d '{"gremlin":"g.V().count().iterate()"}' https://neptune-instance-........neptune.amazonaws.com/gremlin --service neptune-db --header 'host: neptune-instance-.......neptune.amazonaws.com'
```

I'm getting *timeout* exceptions

- Subnet group is good, it's all 3 of my internal subnets
- IAM enabled
- Open security group
- Role is Neptune/RDS full access

What could I be missing in this case?

The cluster is up and running and everything. I've ran over the configuration of the cluster many times and it all looks good, security groups, IAM, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When IAM is enabled, the request needs to be signed using a SigV4 credential.

There is some documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting.html)

However, if you are getting timeouts, and not an error about Access Denied you should check that where you are calling from has access to the Neptune VPC.

Once you resolve the connection issue, you will still need to sign the request if IAM Authentication is enabled. The `awscurl` command will be of the form

```sh
host='https://my-neptune-cluster.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com'

awscurl $host:8182/status/\
        --region us-east-1\
        --service neptune-db\
        --secret_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY\
        --session_token $AWS_SESSION_TOKEN\
        --access_key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
```

Comment: Hi @kelvin, thanks for the quick reply (And thanks for your book!). The command above I use for non-prod account and it works and I get results, prod account doesn't. It's under this assumption that the sigv4 request is setup correctly. I'm not getting access denied. Where could I look for the Neptune VPC access? Everything seems to be setup correctly (from the above points I checked)

Comment: Where are you running the `awscurl` command from? Local machine, EC2 instance, elsewhere ?